AWS Sagemaker Notebook + Panel Tabulator: on_edit not working
I am trying to get some basic example of Panel Tabulator with on_edit working in an AWS SageMaker notebook (Jupyter Lab).
My understanding is that edit_table.on_edit(lambda e: print(e.column, e.row, e.old, e.value)) should fire anytime I leave an edited cell (click elsewhere / use tab / use enter).
The code at the end of my post renders the table, I can edit the strings, but I never see the print output. I also tried to cause a different side-effect like writing a file. Nothing.
I also tried to tabulator.value in a different cell after making the edit. It prints the original data, making me think the problem is in firing the edit, not reacting to it.
What do I need to do in order to make on_edit work in SageMaker notebooks?
(Open to recommendations of other AWS-managed notebooks in case there is one that 'just works')

import panel as pn
import pandas as pd

pn.extension('tabulator')

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['John', 'Jane', 'Bob', 'Alice'],
    'Age': [30, 25, 35, 28],
    'City': ['New York', 'London', 'Paris', 'Tokyo']
})

tabulator = pn.widgets.Tabulator(df)
tabulator.on_edit(lambda e: print(e.column, e.row, e.old, e.value))

pn.Column(tabulator).servable()
# Also tried just tabulator


Running this code in https://panelite.holoviz.org/lab/ produces a log in the developer
console Python callback returned following output: Name 0 John aaa. I expected the output in the notebook, but I don't mind. The event happens and the output changes as a I change the print function.
Running the same code in AWS sage maker renders the table but does nothing (no log on the developer console). Tried Chrome & Firefox.


Output of !jupyter labextension list of my SageMaker Notebook instance:
JupyterLab v4.2.1
/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/python3/share/jupyter/labextensions
        jupyterlab_pygments v0.3.0 enabled OK (python, jupyterlab_pygments)
        jupyterlab-plotly v5.22.0 enabled  X
        @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager v5.0.11 enabled OK (python, jupyterlab_widgets)
        @jupyter-notebook/lab-extension v7.2.0 enabled OK
        @pyviz/jupyterlab_pyviz v3.0.3 enabled OK


   The following extensions may be outdated or specify dependencies that are incompatible with the current version of jupyterlab:
        jupyterlab-plotly
        
   If you are a user, check if an update is available for these packages.
   If you are a developer, re-run with `--verbose` flag for more details.


can you show me the output of !jupyter labextension list

Added to the main post @nabinsademba
